# How to choose between `say` and `said`

Tags: tense

I always use `As someone said, ...` in the comment or answers to respond peoples..

But I happen to see someone's comments are `As you say`,`As someone say`

I cannot determine whether there are problems in the tense?

Both Ok?

Comment: I find it clumsy. And after someone you need `says` - same as _as one says_ (still clumsy)

Comment: @mplungjan: Not sure what you mean by that - there are hundreds of thousands of instances of [as someone said](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22as+someone+said%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1) in Google Books. Though I would usually say *as someone **once** said,* myself.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

While it is true that references of this sort are to things said in the past, it is conventional and indeed reasonable to treat them as present.

What underlies this is the notion that any idea you have advanced in the course of the current conversation is still "present", still under discussion.

Academic discourse in the humanities (but not, apparently, the social sciences) treats even very old articles in the same way:  it is presumed that a disputant continues to hold a position taken up in the past, until it is explicitly withdrawn. And long-dead authors of literary or historical or philosophical works are held to be still "present" in their works as long as readers are still engaging with them: "As Aristotle says,", "As Shakespeare says", "As Gibbon says".

Comment: +1. As an addition: my understanding is that when writing about a narrative, one should use the present tense. I think in the context given in the question, either is acceptable.

Comment: @Daniel Yes, in recounting a plot you tell it as if it were unfolding before your eyes - a convention, I believe, that derives from the fact that this was first practised in English in spoken Prologues and printed "Arguments" to stage plays. But it may derive from some earlier practice in France or among the ancients of which I am unaware.