# "why did he use" or "why does he use"

Tags: grammaticality, tense

Which one of these sentences is grammatically correct?

> - Why **did** the writer use this word?
> - Why **does** the writer use this word?

Comment: Both, although your question is not clear. I think you mean, _"When we discuss an author's works, should we use past or present tenses?"_

Comment: actually, I want to ask question on this website (ell), so I'm wondering which form I should use.

Comment: Grammatically both sentences are correct, but _"Hamburgers eat cows"_ is also grammatically correct. You need to provide a **context** in which you intend to use one of these sentences.

Comment: This is the context: http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/119754/i-had-better-go-now-or-i-have-better-go-now

Comment: You can find your answer here: [Tense usage with dead writers' work](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/234780/tense-usage-with-dead-writers-work)

Comment: Strongly related: http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/7694/how-to-choose-between-say-and-said/7696

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You would use "did" to indicate a single (or repeated) occurrence of something in the past.

You would use "does" to indicate a repeated or regular occurrence of something in the present.

In this case, either works when talking about a written work.  The writer **wrote** it in the past, but you are **reading** it in the present.  The only difference is your own personal point of view -- are you making this comment from the POV of the writer, or from you as the reader?