# "I had better go now." or "I have better go now."

Tags: grammaticality, modality

Why did the writer use "had"? Why didn't he use "have?

> Well, thank you for showing me a great dance. I **had** better go now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The construction *had better + the infinitive without “to”* is used to refer to the present or the future, talking about actions we think people should do or which are desirable in a specific situation.

Saying "*I had better* (do something)", as was noted in the previous answer, the speaker seems to be urging or persuading him/herself to take some action.

Comment: Thank you, what kind of form is this? is it semi-modal?

Comment: I'm not sure it's  a semi-modal like "dare", "used to", but it very much looks like it.

Comment: @Shannak - At the same time, I didn't find it in the list of Semi-Modal Auxiliary Verbs [here](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/Semi-Modal-Auxiliary-Verbs.htm).

Answer (score 3):

This is a kind of exhortation to oneself, which is a second-cousin to the *irrealis* form; it is the not-yet-realized, the not-yet-real, and it is marked by a backshift of tense:

> I **had** better go now.

Compare Middle English *I had lever* and Early Modern *I had rather*.